# Unable to access file larger than 10mb in Android application

Tags: javascript, android, html

I have one `index.html` file and other supporting `css` `javascript` files.

The `css` and `javascript` files are **8mb** , and the html file is nearly **15mb** as it is a flash book (a type of e-book) and as such contains lot of data.

I keep all the data in the html file and now I have to access it from my android application.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What problems are you facing? Show us the logcat, code, etc.

Comment: Pls tell me where should i keep all these data ,so that it will be accessible properly through our application..I have kept all the chapter of e book inside of index.html file.asset folder,raw folders have size limitation.

Comment: ya  i have to reduce the size of images and graphice used in html file..but still this single "index.html" file is above 10 mb.

Answer (score 0):

try php?

filesize cant be set in html from my knowledge, it can in php.

look at this

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apache-increase-php-upload-limit/